IOS, Keyboard changes when obscureText is switched
I have a textfield with obscureText set to true. when I switch it to false the keyboard type changes.
Issue starts while switching to japanese keyboard, if only en keyboard is used, it doesnt appear.
The issue is only found in IOS, seems okay in android.

Issue found at flutter sdk 3.16, 3.19, 3.22.
Sample code below
class PasswordPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PasswordPageState createState() => _PasswordPageState();
}

class _PasswordPageState extends State<PasswordPage> {
  bool _isPasswordVisible = false;
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Password Toggle'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: _passwordController,
                obscureText: !_isPasswordVisible,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      _isPasswordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _isPasswordVisible = !_isPasswordVisible;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Implement your logic for handling the password
                  String password = _passwordController.text;
                  print('Password entered: $password');
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Did you solve your problem? I have the same problem?

no not at the moment.

You can override default keyboard type with keyboardType property on TextFiled:
TextField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
   //....
)

Hope that helps

tried, but didnt work, thanks anyway
